# how to use css to adjust an element's width based on the presence of another element

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have an input box on the left and a button next to it on the right. On some of the pages, I would like to place a checkbox next to the input box and move the button to underneath/below. Is there a way to do it using CSS flexbox or something? I have a JavaScript condition that determines whether the checkbox should be on the page or not, but not sure how I can get things to layout as stated above.

```html
<div>
  <input type="text" />
  <!-- I would like this checkbox to be present only some of the time
  <input type = "checkbox" /> -->
  <button> click me </button>
</div>
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you showed an example with code. Have you looked into media queries?

Comment: as i understand it, media queries adjust based on screen width. I have a javascript condition which would show the checkbox, otherwise not.

Comment: If you could post the HTML and CSS you currently have, we would be able to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simple with the [`adjacent sibling combinator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator), no JavaScript necessary. Simply select any `button` that is immediately adjacent to an `input[type="checkbox"]` and make it display `block` (rather than `inline`).

```css
input[type="checkbox"] + button {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="text" />
  <input type = "checkbox" />
  <button> click me </button>
</div>

<div>
  <input type="text" />
  <button> click me </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, that is what I am asking: how to use a class to achieve the layout I want.

Comment: @Riz see the updated answer. i was overthinking it.

Comment: ah thanks! how can I ensure this doesn't happen with all buttons, but with a specific one?

Comment: add `class="whateveryouwant"` to the `button` element in the HTML, then in the CSS replace `button` with `button.whateveryouwant` (or just `.whateveryouwant`). see [class selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Class_selectors).

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this?

Run the snippet below:

```js
//here we are getting each element by its id
var check = document.getElementById("check");
var input = document.getElementById("input");
var button = document.getElementById("button");
//this is the condition we're using (it could be anything but it was easy to use a boolean for this example)
var bool = false;

//here is the function we're calling on click
function clickMe() {
//when button is clicked we set bool from false to true
bool = true;
//if bool is true we we will apply the following styles to the check and button
if (bool === true) {
check.style.display = "inline-block";
button.style.display = "block";
}
}
```

```css
#check {
display: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="check"><input id="input"><button id="button" onclick="clickMe();">Click Me</button>
```

Comment: yes, something like that except i was just wondering if there is some clever css that makes it happen automatically if the checkbox is present instead of explicity using javascript. In your example, you are using a button click to make checkbox appear/disappear, but in my case the checkbox's presence would be determined by some other condition on page load.

Comment: If you're doing this based on a condition then manipulating DOM elements is best done with JS. - As you can see, we are targeting each element by its id and applying CSS styles when necessary. If you could provide a more definitive example of your desired functionality I can update the example.

Comment: fair enough. thanks.

Comment: I've also included comments to show what is happening. - If this helps in any way please upvote or mark correct. Thanks, and happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Would recommend toggling the style of the parent

```js
function toggleClass() {
  const element = document.getElementById("container")
  element.classList.toggle("toggle");
}
```

```css
#checkbox {
  display:none;
}

.toggle #checkbox {
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <input type="text"/>
  <input id="checkbox" type="checkbox"/>
  <button onClick="toggleClass()">Button</button>
</div>
```